# JavaScript OnClick Custom Button in Console

Tags: javascript, custom-button

All -

I am trying to create a custom button for the Sales console. This button is calling a specific E-Mail Template and prepopulating data.

I know how to leverage the JavaScript for Custom Buttons that bring up web pages or links for the Salesforce Console, but when I try to combine that functionality with the JavaScript to auto select a template for e-mail I get the following error:

Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Here is my code......what am I missing here?

```
srcUp('
     location.replace('
            /email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Case.Id}&p3_lkid={!Case.Id}&rtype=003&p2_lkid={!Case.ContactId}&template_id=00XG0000001bHA9/
     ');
');
```

Comment: I'm exceptionally sure you can't have a newline in a literal string like this.

Comment: Are you including the integration.js script? {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/33.0/integration.js")}

Answer (score 1):

Try using following:-

srcUp("/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Case.Id}&p3_lkid={!Case.Id}&rtype=003&p2_lkid={!Case.ContactId}&template_id=00XG0000001bHA9/");

Answer (score 0):

Try to change with this:

```
srcUp("
     location.replace('
            /email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Case.Id}&p3_lkid={!Case.Id}&rtype=003&p2_lkid={!Case.ContactId}&template_id=00XG0000001bHA9/
     ');
");
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve it, same error